# General metadata crowd sourcing

Tags: linux, open-source, metadata

There is a program I use that let's you organize content and saves the metadata in a sqlite database.

I'd like to know if there is any open source program for linux that let's people crowd source the metadata saved in a general sqlite database, so that people could vote on the metadata and each person could select to add missing metadata, or overwrite all metadata from the metadata with more positive votes.

If there isn't some program like this. I would like to know if there is any open source code that implements this for a specific database schema instead of a general one.

Comment: Can you clarify about the source files, images, text, video?

Comment: Content independent for the general. Or any one of them for the specific.

Comment: If the metadata is different you can't use standard tables (or they will become very wide). So sqlite will not be the right database. Have you think about something like key:value store?